# Imagemagick cannot read tif files

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have just installed imagemagick for php with tiff support (--with-tiff=yes option has been used for configuring):

```
identify -list format | grep TIFF
  EPT  rw-   Encapsulated PostScript with TIFF preview
  EPT2  rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Level II with TIFF preview
  EPT3  rw+   Encapsulated PostScript Level III with TIFF preview
  PTIF* rw+   Pyramid encoded TIFF
  TIFF* rw+   Tagged Image File Format (LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3)
 TIFF64* rw-   Tagged Image File Format (64-bit) (LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3)
```

But when i try to load a tif image, i receive the following error:

```
no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501 File: /var/www/test.php, Line: 44 Trace:
```

I can load the file on my local pc and open it - works fine.
Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: You can check if PHP's imagick library can work with TIFF files by running `php -i | grep TIFF`

Comment: Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF
ImageMagick supported formats => [...] TIFF, TIFF64, [...]
Looks like it should be supported. Any other ideas what to check?

Comment: First thing I would do is a simple convert with the file in the same folder as the code. You also want to post your convert command so we can see it as it looks like you have a server 501 error.

Comment: After having spend most of my night searching for a solution, i finally figures out, that my php.ini did not provide enough resources to process (very) large tif files. I've now increased `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` and now everything works even with large files. Hope that helps anyone in future!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with the answer @ElGauchooo